# Compactness of the set of finite Borel measures

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, compactness, borel-measures

Suppose $X$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$. Let $\mathcal M(X)$ denote the space of all finite Borel measures on $X$. Is $\mathcal M(X)$ compact under some commonly used topology?

I have very little knowledge of functional analysis to answer this on my own. Hence posting here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is obviously not. Consider a sequence of measures $\mu_n = n \mathbb{1}_{x=0}$, $n \in \mathbb N$. This has no convergent subsequence.